# Can I develop a program in C# for my calculator?

Tags: processor, calculator, .net-micro-framework

Does those calculators have some type of a processor like a computer?  Is it possible to program to them? And finally, is it somehow possible to run the .NET Micro Framework on it?

Thank you.

[image]
<sub>(source: [made-in-china.com](http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00aCAEjhmggQkT/Scientific-Calculator-with-Natural-Textbook-Display-FX-82ES.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [ecarepackage.org](http://www.ecarepackage.org/ecareshop/images/calculator.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

The more expensive TI's have general purpose processors such as Z80 or m68000, which can be programmed *(usually in BASIC or assembly)*.  There are no current implementations of the .Net framework that run on them - you could be the first to create it!

The cheaper ones have the logic built directly into the IC, and are not programmable in any way.

Answer (score 3):

There are some programmable calculators out there but I am not aware of any that will run the .NET Framework.